# Why is the Tamron 150-600mm lens so cheap?

Tags: zoom, tamron

The newly released Tamron 150-600mm f/5-6.3 SP Di VC USD seems to have garnered very positive reviews at a killer price ($1069). Tamron seems to have not compromised on optics (comparable image quality to the Canon 100-400), build quality, AF performance or the effectiveness of the image stabilization. The only real compromise seems to be that the lens 1/3 stop slower than your typical tele-zoom at the long end.

Given that zoom lenses are always a delicate balancing act of compromises, where could Tamron have compromised to release this lens at this price point? Is this simply an extreme case of a third party lens being a whole lot cheaper than the first-party alternatives?

Comment: Some would say that optics comparable to the Canon 100-400mm f/4-5.6 L is a considerable compromise.

Comment: See http://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2014/01/tamron-150-600-telezoom-shootout

Answer (score 4):

I'm not party to any engineering details and haven't yet used the lens so this is purely speculation, however...

The Canon 100-400 (a first party competitor) was originally released in 1998, it's likely that since then manufacturing methods and designs have improved considerably allowing Tamron to produce a lens of good quality for a lower price. Obviously whilst the Canon lens has continued to sell, Canon has seen no need to replace it or update the design (despite many calls to do that).

Canon can also charge a premium for it's lens as people associate them with a higher quality product.

Note also the Tamron is considerably heavier at 2kg vs 1.3kg, which some people would argue is a significant compromise.

Comment: Also note that the Canon 100-400 is a L (Luxury) lens, which are the Canon's premium grade lens.

Comment: @ChrisFletcher Good point about the weight. I missed that. Though I'd guess that most of the added weight comes from the extra glass required to reach to 600mm, I doubt a Canon 150-600 would weigh any less.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi You're probably right about the weight of a Canon equivalent. 
I've been a 100-400 owner myself for several years and I'm very interested in this and Canons potential response after a long time with no progress in this area.

Comment: @YaoBoLu The "L" is really just branding. While it generally denotes a high quality "professional" lens, there are several high quality (and expensive!) lenses without the "L" designation. In effect, the "L" is simply an excuse to charge higher prices. That's not to say the "L" lenses aren't usually a significant step up from most consumer lenses, but the "L" designation really doesn't tell you anything meaningful about a lens's performance.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi - actually, I think that what Yao Bo Lu was trying to say is that you are paying extra for an L on it (branding) rather than quality.  I would disagree with that though as L lenses does say something about the quality of the lens.  I don't know of any L lenses that perform below the level of a comparable non-L lens within Canon's line.  In fact, in pixel to pixel comparisons, every L lens I has actually is a better value per $ (in terms of sharpness alone) than the non-L lenses I had prior.  It's held true for all 3 of the L lenses that I have so far, though millage may vary.

Comment: "L" is not "just" branding but is used for lens with particular attention on several point used by professionnal like (depending of main use at creation by canon) "waterproof", limited aberration, Autofocus speed and sound, shock resistance. Non L lens could give sometime very good photo but generaly doens't reach color, piqué, bocket when out of central point. See http://www.dpreview.com/articles/3135549652/lens-reviews-explained?utm_campaign=internal-link&utm_source=mainmenu&utm_medium=text&ref=mainmenu for an idea of those details

Comment: @AJHenderson I'm not saying that L lenses aren't generally better than non-L's. I'm saying that just sticking an L on a lens doesn't tell you anything _in general_ about a lens's performance characteristics. For instance, the 100 macro and the 100 L IS macro are practically indistinguishable IQ-wise. In that sense, "L" is just branding.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi If you use them 3-4 times a year you may think it is just branding. If you use them every day to make a living you quickly realize there is more to a lens than image quality - reliability under hard use is also a compelling reason to own one lens over another.

Comment: There have been some "L" lenses that were stinkers optically compared to their non-"L" brothers, especially if you go back a few years. The point of "L" is that it offers a specific feature set that may make the difference between getting the shot and *not* getting the shot under a specific set of circumstances. They're not expensive because they're well-built; they're well-built because they're expensive. The Luxury feature may be speed, extreme focal length, extreme macro, tilt/shift, etc., but the "L" means "not everyone needs this, but when you do, you do".

Comment: @StanRogers I would have thought it was just the opposite - They're not well built because they are expensive: they're expensive because they're well built. Using superior materials (or more materials due to increased thicknesses) and machining to higher tolerances always costs more.

Comment: @MichaelClark Again, I'm trying to point out that the "L" designation tells you very little about the underlying characteristics that caused it to be designated as such. For some it may be optical quality, for others reliability or weather sealing or whatever. And as such, it's just branding. As a counter-example, "DO" is not just branding. It tells you that the lens is likely to be lighter than a conventional design and (at least with current designs) a fair bit softer than its non-DO brethren.

Comment: @MichaelClark - the "L" lenses were going to be expensive anyway because of their optical features. Cheaping out on the mechanicals would be a good way to make sure that nobody ever bought them; the build quality doesn't amount to much as a manufacturing expense, as it would with a much cheaper optical formulation. It's one thing to add fifty bucks or so to the manufacturing cost of a $2500 lens; it's quite another to add it to something that's targeted at a $500 retail price point.

Comment: @StanRogers Point well taken. It is the case recently that some of the lower priced "L" lenses are now selling not too far above that $500 price point, though. 70-200 f/4, 17-40 f/4, 24-105 f/4. And yes, these are all older designs for which Canon long ago recouped their R&D investment. But I think the lower prices are more a response to market pressure from some of the recent offerings of Sigma, Tamron, et al.